# Surviving a reboot with AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, dns, amazon-cloudfront

We all know that CloudFlare has a feature where if your server is offline, it will start serving up a cached version of your website - whether something has gone terribly wrong, or whether you're doing a simple restart.

I've been searching the net high and low, of how to do the same thing with CloudFront but I just can't seem to be able to dig out any kind of resource in relation to this matter.

Do you have any pointers?

Comment: Any reason you want to use CloudFront when CloudFlare has the feature you want? I find that CloudFlare is generally better than CloudFront except in a few specific use cases.

Comment: @MarkB I just want to see if it is possible with CloudFront

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best idea is to put a load balancer (e.g. using [Elastic Load Balancer](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/)) in front of your server and spin up another server which replicates your existing site. You can also use an [Elastic IP Address](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html) to reroute traffic if a particular server falls offline.

You can then use a shared MySQL server (e.g. AWS RDS in a Multi-AZ configuration for extra redundancy) plus a GlusterFS to keep the website document root on both web servers in sync. DigitalOcean have a guide for this here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/automating-the-deployment-of-a-scalable-wordpress-site

I would highly recommend CloudFlare over AWS CloudFront, there are many other benefits CloudFlare has (e.g. [CloudFlare has HTTP2 support where CloudFront does not](https://blog.cloudflare.com/http-2-demo-under-the-hood/)).

Comment: Cloudfront recently added support for HTTP2.
[Cloudfront supports HTTP/2](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2016/09/amazon-cloudfront-now-supports-http2/)

Answer (score 3):

CloudFront would fetch your assets from your origin, store them at the edge location upon first viewer request and return cached version to the subsequent viewer requests.

After object is expired at the edge location, CloudFront will contact the origin again to determine whether the cache has the latest version of the object and, if not, to get the latest version. If your origin server is not available at this time, CloudFront will return [stale] cached version of the object to the viewer.

Please see CloudFront documentation here - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/HTTPStatusCodes.html#HTTPStatusCodes-no-custom-error-pages.

Comment: Yes I am aware of those facts but how do you route the traffic there as a fallback?

Comment: Not sure if I understand your question. How do we route traffic where?

Comment: My initial question is about how to route traffic to CloudFront when the server is down.

Answer (score 3):

Point your traffic to CloudFront **all the time**. CloudFront will pull the content from your server on as-needed basis (i.e. if CloudFront already has a fresh-enough cached copy of a page or another resource, it will serve that cached copy). If your server is down due to reboot or because something went wrong and CloudFront has a cached copy of your page, CloudFront will serve the cached copy, regardless of how fresh it is.

If you need to make sure that a particular resource is in CloudFront's cache before your server goes down, just hit that page with a web browser. This will make CloudFront to serve the page from it's cache or pull it from your origin server; in either case, the net result is that the page is cached in CloudFront.

Comment: So there is no way to conditionally route the traffic there based on a healthcheck?

Comment: Say your website is www.xyz.com. The DNS entry for www.xyz.com needs to point at something. Dynamically switching the DNS, so that one moment it points at your hosting provider and the next moment it points to CloudFront is not a viable option. DNS propagation time is usually longer than it takes for a server to reboot. So www.xyz.com should *always* point at the thing that does the health check. You can add your own health check server and make www.xyz.com point at it, but CloudFront already performs the health check as I described, so just point www.xyz.com at CloudFront.

Answer (score 2):

Cloudfront just caches static content. It is nothing more than a CDN.

If your server needs to reboot, I assume its a standard web stack. If so, you should use a ELB with multiple machines. You can probably get away with micro instances if you think cloudfront is doing the bulk of the work.

If you have a static website, just use S3. It doesnt reboot, and you can CDN via cloudfront easily. No need for ELB